# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka - EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range in

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot app (**app0**) that uses Spring Cloud Stream Kafka to read from a topic.

There are two other apps (**app1**, **app2**) that produce messages into that topic.

**app1** publishes messages using an interface OrderSource:

```
public interface OrderSource{ 

    String OUTPUT_PAYMENT = Topic.PAYMENT_RESULTS;

    @Output(OrderSource.OUTPUT_PAYMENT)
    MessageChannel output();
```

For instance:

```
orderSource.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(order).build(), 500);
```

In this case, app0 reads the messages from app1 without any problem.

**app2** publishes its messages using KafkaTemplate:

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> delivery = kafkaTemplate.send(Topic.PAYMENT_RESULTS, "{ ... }");
try {
    SendResult<Integer, String> result = delivery.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In this case I am observing the following exception from `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter`:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 152
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Apparently it is trying to extract headers from the payload of the message. How can I prevent this exception from happening while supporting both sources of messages (KafkaTemplate and OrderSource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate with non Spring-Cloud-Stream apps, you need to configure the `headerMode` on the consumer to `raw`.

You will also need to do the same on the producer for **app1** too so he doesn't embed headers.

See [consumer properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties) and [producer properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties).

Comment: Thanks Gary. A couple of questions: what are the consecuences of not embedding the headers? Will they still be sent?

Comment: Kafka has no concept of headers; that's why we have to embed them in the payload. The only header transferred (by default) is the content type; it's only needed if you are relying on the binder to perform any complex message conversion in the consuming app. If you need that, or have configured the sending (app1) binder to embed any custom headers then you are out of luck. But a work-around there would be to use the embedded converter in your app2 before sending. Or, use different topics for app1/app2 and configure app0 accordingly.

Comment: Everything's clear now, thanks!! Could you point out any reference to do this:  `a work-around there would be to use the embedded converter in your app2 before sending`

Comment: Did you mean to use `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.embedHeaders()` in app2 and send the resulting byte array?

Comment: Exactly, yes; that's what I meant.